# Java & Flash in one project: How to organize it in Eclipse and Git?

Tags: java, eclipse, flash, git

I have a web project that contains components in different languages: two components in Java (that have to run on different servers), a component in ActionScript, and a component in C#.

I would like to have all of them in one manageable chunk. The two Java components are being developed in Eclipse and use Ant for building.

So far the Java components are separate projects in separate Git repos, the Flash and C# components are not under git, and their sources are on the local machines of their respective developers.

How can I turn them into, sort of, one entity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I can answer your question completely but I can add a little to the discussion.  Git by nature I believe (someone correct me if I'm wrong) supports a very fine granular structure when it comes to repositories.  In other words I think your best option would be to have one git Repo for the each java source, one for the ActionScript source, and the last for the C# source.  The reason being that I believe the community is focused on having one repo for each project.  I am only familiar with eclipse so I highly recommend [EGit](http://eclipse.org/egit/).  For ActionScript I use FlashBuilder and the same EGit plugin.  I recommend doing the same.  As far as C# goes (I assume you are Using Visual Studio) [Git Extensions](http://code.google.com/p/gitextensions/) seems to be a popular option.

Note:  Egit can easily be found in the Eclipse marketplace if you have it installed.