# Multiple GIT repositories and Access Token authentications not storing separately in Eclipse Secure Storage

Tags: git, eclipse, bitbucket, access-token

I recently converted all my BitBucket GIT repositories over to Access Tokens as per their requirements.

In Eclipse I have multiple projects, each with their own repository, so individual Access Tokens. There certainly a difference of opinion on multiple repositories or single is better (as per this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11541162/multiple-git-repositories-for-each-eclipse-project-or-one-git-repository) but a big single repository will create more trouble than it's worth.

Using the Secure Store to hold the "credentials" only stores per domain (i.e. bitbucket.org)

So it can only hold one repository at at a time and its Secure Storage details are overwritten each time a different repositories creds are entered.

SVN used to hold multiple entries per site.

I don't see much evidence of this being a problem with other people, and it seems fairly fundamental. So, I'm wondering if I'm missing something or there is something I've not configured.

I've tried a clean Eclipse config and wiped the Secure Storage completely and it's not had any effect.

Changing the domain to try and incorporate the repository details doesn't help either, as it just reverts to the domain only. This does create multiple GIT entries in Secure Storage, but they obviously don't work.

Does anyone else have multiple GIT repository entries for the same domain in Eclipse Secure Storage ?

Any suggestion is much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You are accessing the same Bitbucket instance via HTTPS and using different(!) access tokens as passwords for the same(!) account/username, right? The purpose of access tokens is to give another one, e.g. a bot, access rights to a specific repository only. That makes your question an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) as there are better solutions for your root problem (for example, Bitbucket with a single SSH key works fine for me, is more secure and easier to use).

Comment: That's a fair point. I did start with SSH but thought Access Tokens were easier. I misunderstood, so you're point about it being an XY problem is exactly right. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

If Eclipse Secure Storage is working as a git credential helper, you are looking for [credential.useHttpPath](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-credentialuseHttpPath).

```
git config --global credential.useHttpPath true
```

> When acquiring credentials, consider the "path" component of an http
> or https URL to be important. Defaults to false. See gitcredentials[7] for more information.

And [more information](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials#Documentation/gitcredentials.txt-useHttpPath),

> By default, Git does not consider the "path" component of an http URL
> to be worth matching via external helpers. This means that a
> credential stored for https://example.com/foo.git will also be used
> for https://example.com/bar.git. If you do want to distinguish these
> cases, set this option to true.

Comment: The question is about EGit/JGit, not the command line Git you are talking about.

Comment: @howlger I think they should respect git configuration. If not, they should have their own configuration with corresponding variables and keys.

Comment: Who is _they_? `git ...` is a Git command line command that can be used in git-core, the Git command line implementation. JGit is another implementation of Git in Java and EGit is based on JGit and is the Git support in the Eclipse IDE. EGit/JGit do not require git-core nor delegate to git-core. Your answer would be a helpful comment, but as an answer it's the wrong answer to the question asked.

Answer (score 0):

You obviously accessing the same Bitbucket instance via HTTPS using **different** [**repository** access tokens](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/repository-access-tokens/) as passwords for the **same account**/username. But the purpose of access tokens is to give another one, e.g. a bot, access rights to a specific repository only. That makes your question an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) as there are **better solutions** in the sense of more secure and easier to use for your root problem.

So better use one of the following methods to authenticate yourself in all your Git repositories, including Git repositories that you will create in the future and Git repositories that you do not yet have access to but will gain access to in the future:

- Single **SSH key** (which works fine for me): click on your profile icon in the top right corner and choose *Manage Account > SSH keys*, or
- Single **HTTP access tokens** for all repositories you can access with your account rather than for a specific one: *Manage Account > HTTP access tokens*